# PigeonHole/Dovecot configuration for Sieve extension "Spamtest" with respect to "rspamd"

Tags: dovecot, sieve, rspamd

I try to configure the Sieve extension "Spamtest" (see [Pigeonhole Sieve: Spamtest and Virustest Extensions](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/sieve/extensions/spamtest_virustest/)) for rspamd. Rspamd is configured to add the extended mail header (`extended_spam_headers = true`).

The header looks like

`X-Spamd-Result: default: False [-1.10 / 15.00];`

I am wondering what the different parts of the header are. Obviously, the back part `[-1.10 / 15.00]` is the score. However, I am wondering what the part "default: False" means? Where does it come from? Is it fixed? (I did some googling and have always only found examples exactly like this.)

Would the following configuration for Sieve "Spamtest" and regex pattern be OK?

```
sieve_spamtest_status_type = score
sieve_spamtest_status_header = X-Spamd-Result: default: False \[(-?[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+) / [[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\]
sieve_spamtest_max_header    = X-Spamd-Result: default: False \[-?[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+ / ([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+)\]
```

The pattern obvisouly assumes that "default: False" never changes, but I am unsure if this is a safe bet.

Answer (score 0):

Its not fixed, you just won't see `True` in that context. Because if the the action associated with that score was `reject`.. your Sieve script would not ordinarily process that headers, because it did not receive that message.